# Concurrency issues in serverless functions (AWS / Azure)

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, aws-lambda, concurrency, azure-functions

My function is processing events from a queue service.

Each message in queue will contain a unique ID and it is expected that messages with same ID should be processed only once. It is possible that there will be multiple messages with same  in the queue.

To prevent it, I've defined function logic as:

```
uniqueId = deserialize_queue_message();
if (check_in_progress(uniqueId))
  throw;
set_in_progress(uniqueId);
do_work();
```

function scaling is what worries me: if 2 instances start execution *at the same time*, they will both pass the `check_in_progress(uniqueId)` condition and continue to `do_work()` which will result in duplicate message processing.

What are the usual approaches to this? How can I prevent this *at the same time* issue?

I'm thinking of adding a unique constraint on DB level so pair (uniqueID, in_progress) so an exception is thrown on `set_in_progress(uniqueId)` step but this forces me to have uniqueID and in_progress in the same DB table and I would like to avoid this if possible.

Comment: The usual solution is to store your status in a database, which it seems that you're already doing. However, to make this work it's critical that _everything be wrapped in a transaction._

Comment: Be aware of Amazon SQS [deduplication features](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/using-messagededuplicationid-property.html) and [idempotency](https://matthewbonig.com/2019/06/04/idempotent-lambdas/) options using DynamoDB.

Comment: @kdgregory this really does seem like a common issue, but it is hard to find discussions or examples online. Perhaps there is some feature of functions that prevents this that I am not aware of?

SQS FIFO is not an option for us due to throughput. Will look more into having a dedicated table for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you can accept 5 min ID deduplication window then you can try using [SQS FIFO](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-queues.html), which guarantees only-once delivery and has deduplication logic (with 5-min deduplication interval)

Comment: Looks good, thanks! For my case, I can not use FIFO do to its throughput constraints, so I'm looking for a cloud agnostic solution

Comment: @TadijaBagarić - Understood. In that case using dedicated table sounds like a generic solution that would work for any cloud. Also, just in case you haven't seen this, SQS FIFO supports up to 15,000 messages per second (up to 60,000 mps in some regions) with high throughput mode. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/high-throughput-fifo.html